# Canon 120 LiDE Scanner VirtualBox Windows 7

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, windows-7, canon

I recently purchased a Canon 120 LiDE Scanner that does not work with Ubuntu 14.04.

I was wondering if it is possible to use the scanner via a Windows 7 x64 VirtualBox even though the scanner is not detected on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

*Open a terminal.*

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

*Run it:*

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall libusb-dev build-essential libsane-dev git-core
$ git clone git://git.debian.org/sane/sane-backends.git
$ cd sane-backends
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var
$ sudo make
$ sudo make install
```

*Check if recognized his idVendor and idProduct, run:*

```
$ dmesg
```

*This command should report something like:*

```
...... usb ?-?: New USB device found, idVendor=04a9, idProduct=190e
```

*Continue running:*

```
 $ sudo nano /lib/udev/rules.d/40-libsane.rules
```

*And add the following lines at the end of file:*

```
# Canon CanoScan Lide 120
 ATTRS{idVendor}=="04a9", ATTRS{idProduct}=="190e", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> Paste. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> Save file. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> Close nano.

*Continue running:*

```
$ sudo nano /etc/sane.d/genesys.conf
```

*And add the following lines at the end of file:*

```
# Canon CanoScan Lide 120
 usb 0x04a9 0x190e
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> Paste. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> Save file. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> Close nano.